# Trying to check web content on android during Robotium test

Tags: java, android, automated-tests, robotium

My application is service running on background and making changes to network traffic. I want to make a test with Robotium calling for web source and checking the the page.
Here is my code for calling for web content:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    Log.d(TAG, "Looking for text ["+expected+"] at address ["+url+"]");
    getSolo().getCurrentActivity().startActivity(i);
    getSolo().waitForWebElement(By.textContent(expected), timeout, false);
```

Here are few things i have tried but with no result

```
    bool foundContent = getSolo().waitForText(expected));
    foundContent = foundContent | getSolo().getCurrentWebElements().size() > 0;
    foundContent = foundContent | getSolo().getWebElement(By.tagName("div"), 0));
```

It is enough for me when the test checks "Yeah the page contain word porn" or "Nope the page contain word porn" but if its possible I would be glad if have access also to whole page code in string if its possible.

My first question here so i hope its OK
Thank you for help in advance!

P.S.: I read that [solo object have method `waitForWebElement` returning bool](http://robotium.googlecode.com/svn/doc/index.html) (false when the content is not present till timeout) in 4.0 but in code (using 4.0 jar Robotium) and in [other reference](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.jayway.android.robotium/robotium-solo/4.0/com/jayway/android/robotium/solo/Solo.java#Solo) there is only a void. Is it something that they are still working on?

Comment: Use Robotium 4.1. You can use searchText, waitForText, waitForWebElement etc.

Comment: Thx for advice I could not find info about 4.1 version... I have now Solo 4.1 and tried out waitForText(".*"+expected+".*"), searchText(".*"+expected+".*") and waitForWebElement(By.textContent(expected)). Everyone returns false even when the page loads on emulator with that content (i have page "http://example.iana.org/" looking for content "Example Domain")